# Click on point labels through zoom canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-7, internet-explorer-6, jqplot

I have `onclick` event on point labels.
Works fine on IE8+, Firefox and Chrome.
Zoom also works fine.

But on IE7, IE6 I can't click on point labels because we have `jqplot-event-canvas` and `jqplot-zoom-canvas` and others on front.

When I increase `z-index` for `<DIV class="chartPointWrapper"> ... </div>` we can click on point labels. But zoom is not working.

Do you know any solution to handle chart zoom and onclick event on point labels?

Thanks.

Comment: how did u added click event on labels?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to your problem, I believe, is [in EDIT2 of my answer to a similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10428034/613495).
Effectively, you must apply z-index to all canvas appropriately so they preserve they intended order.

*For answer to question in @Swapnil Chincholkar 's comment above, please [see this code sample](http://jsfiddle.net/zRhXs/18/). It shows how you can use the `jqplotClick` to detect clicks on the points. As [you could read here](https://bitbucket.org/cleonello/jqplot/issue/53/click-event-for-data-points) only when you are on or close to a point the `neighbor` variable is not null. You could observe that the highlighter plugin uses the `neighbor` variable in the same way to show its tooltip.*